# twig template uncompleted tags

Tags: variables, tags, twig

I'm going to use twig as mail template engine for public service.
The problem I have is that if user uncompleted twig variable tag - this will cause exception and will brake the system.

```
Hello, {{ name  *(instead {{ name }})*

message body
```

I there any way to ignore errors in twig syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an option you can suppress an Twig_Error_Syntax with an *registerUndefinedFunctionCallback* or *registerUndefinedFilterCallback*

you can try something like this:

```
$twig->registerUndefinedFunctionCallback(function ($name) { 

   if (function_exists($name)) {
    return new Twig_Function_Function($name);
   }

   return false; 
});
```

it should return false.

or another way simply catch an Exception, at the moment when twig is trying to parse:

```
try {

   $twig->parse($twig->tokenize($template));


} catch (Twig_Error_Syntax $e) {

    // here you are    

}
```